# How can I make two "user" editable areas in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

is there a way to have two posting areas in Wordpress, for clients who can not go into any HTML? Basically the template has 3 columns. One is vertical nav, thats no prob. Second is like a "sidebar" but where the main post will go, a skinny column. Third is large, "main area" size, but will also be user editable content. Does that make sense? Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. In particular, check out the Widgets and multiple Sidebars. You can have no main page area at all and just treat your columns as three sidebars; and use the Posts widget wherever you'd like, perhaps with different Categories.

Or use a "Text" widget and put html with a textarea in any format you want.